# Inverse element of

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Given the extension $ \dfrac{\mathbb Q[x]}{\langle x^3-5\rangle}: \mathbb Q$ and $\alpha =1+x^2+\langle x^3-5\rangle \in \dfrac{\mathbb Q[x]}{\langle x^3-5 \rangle}$, find $\alpha^{-1}$.

Can somebody give a hint? or an answer? please?

Comment: why did you remove $ \frac{\mathbb Q[x]}{<x^3-5>}$ @tilper ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general element of this ring looks like $a + bx + cx^2$. Suppose this were the inverse of $1+x^2$. Then:

\begin{align*}
1 &= (1+x^2)(a+bx+cx^2)\\
&= a + bx + (a+c)x^2 + bx^3 +cx^4
\end{align*}

In this ring, $x^3 = 5$ so:

\begin{align*}
1 &= a + bx + (a+c)x^2 +5b + 5cx \\
&=(a+5b) + (b+5c)x + (a+c)x^2.
\end{align*}

This tells us that $$a + 5b =1\\ b+5c = 0 \\ a + c = 0$$

I trust you can take it from here.

---

I can't resist adding an alternative approach. If you don't have a background in linear algebra, or this seems arcane, feel free to disregard it.

Let's consider your ring as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then it is three dimensional, and an easy basis would be $1,x,x^2$. Define the linear transformation on this vector space that multiplies a polyomial by $x$. Now let us find the matrix (call it $A$) of this transformation with respect to the basis above:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 5 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}_.$$

The cool thing is that if you want to find the inverse of $x^2+1$, you can instead find the inverse of the matrix $A^2 + I$ and then express it as a linear combination of $I, A, A^2$! In this case we have that:

\begin{align*}
(A^2 + I)^{-1} &= \frac{1}{26}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -5 & 25 \\ 5 & 1 & -5 \\ -1 & 5 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \frac{1}{26} I + \frac{5}{26} A - A^2.
\end{align*}

This tells us the the inverse of $x^2+1$ is $$\frac{1}{26} + \frac{5}{26}x - \frac{1}{26}x^2.$$

Comment: So I have to solve the system of equations and then I substitute  a,b,c in the inverse proposition a+bx+c$x^2$?

Comment: Yep, that will do it!

Comment: and that's the answer right?

Comment: I rather your first answer 

Answer (score 2):

Use the Euclidean algorithm,

> $$p(x)(x^2+1) + q(x)(x^3-5)=1$$

$$x^3-5 = x(x^2+1)+(-x-5)$$
$$x^2+1 = -x(-x-5) +5(-x-5)+26$$
$$-x-5 = -{x\over 26}(26)-4$$
$$26 = {2\over 13}(4)+0$$

Now as usual reverse the process to produce a polynomial inverse modulo $x^3-5$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^3-5$ is a polynomial of degree $3$, every element in $k:= \dfrac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{\langle x^3-5\rangle}$ has a representative of degree at most $2$. Thus we are looking for a polynomial $\beta:=a + bx + cx^2 + \langle x^3 - 5\rangle$ where $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Q}$ and such that $\alpha\beta = 1 + \langle x^3 + 5\rangle$.

Now
\begin{align*}\alpha\beta &= a + bx + (a+c)x^2 + bx^3 + cx^4 + \langle x^3 -5\rangle \\ &= (a+5b) + (b+5c)x + (a+c)x^2 + \langle x^3 -5\rangle
\end{align*}

Therefore

$$
\begin{cases}
a+5b = 1 & \\ b + 5c = 0 & \\ a + c = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Solving this we get

$$a = \dfrac{1}{26} \qquad b = \dfrac{5}{26} \qquad c = \dfrac{-1}{26}$$

So $\alpha^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{26}(1 + 5x - x^2) + \langle x^3 - 5\rangle$.

Comment: If instead of $ \mathbb Q$ is $ \mathbb Z_5$ the process to find $\alpha^{-1}$ would be similar?

Comment: @AnneliseToft Indeed. With any field it would be similar, but when it has a positive characteristic you have to take that into account.

Comment: a positive characteristic? what's that?

Comment: But if it's similar in which step will I include that the coefficients are from $ \mathbb Z_5$ ?

Comment: When you solve the system of equations (when dividing, you have to use the inverse in the corresponding field, e.g. in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, $2^{-1} = 3$).

Comment: And for example in $\mathbb{Z}_7,  4^{-1}=3$?

Comment: No, $4\cdot 3 = 5 \neq 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ so $4^{-1}$ cannot be $3$. However $4\cdot 2 = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ so $4^{-1} = 2$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't do it (I mean you helped me, why would I do that?)

Comment: I assumed it wasn't you. Someone did and I don't see why.